# Как, после получения урона персонажем, дать ему неуязвимость?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Изучаю Unity 3D, пишу на C#.
Экспериментирую на одной игре. Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой: как, при получении урона, главный герой получает неуязвимость, например на 2 секунды (само получение урона уже реализовал)?

Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;

public class Character : Unit
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 3.0F;
    [SerializeField]
    private int lives = 5;

    public int Lives
    {
        get { return lives; }
        set 
        {
            if (value < 5) lives = value;
            livesBar.Refresh ();
        }
    }
    private LivesBar livesBar;

    private int _prevTimeStamp = 0;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 15.0F;

    private bool isGrounded = false;

    private Bullet bullet;

    private CharState State
    {
        get { return (CharState)animator.GetInteger ("State"); }
        set { animator.SetInteger("State", (int)  value); }
    }


    new private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private Animator animator;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        livesBar = FindObjectOfType<LivesBar> ();
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ();

        bullet = Resources.Load<Bullet> ("Bullet");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckGround ();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Idle;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) Shoot ();
        if (Input.GetButton ("Horizontal")) Run ();
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) Jump ();
        if (gameObject.transform.position.y < -10)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player Dead");
            SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name);
        }
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Vector3 direction = transform.right * Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0F;

        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Run;
    }

    private void Jump()
    {

        rigidbody.AddForce (transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);


    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;   position.y += 0.8F;
        Bullet newBullet = Instantiate (bullet, position, bullet.transform.rotation) as Bullet;

        newBullet.Parent = gameObject;
        newBullet.Direction = newBullet.transform.right * (sprite.flipX ? -1.0F : 1.0F);
    }

    public override void ReceiveDamage()
    {
        {
            // запишем тукущее количество тиков, со старта ОС, и будем
            // записывать каждый раз в переменную для срванения с предыдущим
            var timeStamp = Environment.TickCount;
            _prevTimeStamp = _prevTimeStamp == 0 ? timeStamp : _prevTimeStamp;

            if(TimeSpan.FromTicks(timeStamp - _prevTimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds < 2000 && _prevTimeStamp != timeStamp)// где 2000, миллисекунды, или же 2 секунды
            {
                return;
            }
            // если время вышло, то запишем текущее значение timemeStamp в _prevTimeStamp
            // в следующий раз будем сверять именно его.
            _prevTimeStamp = timeStamp;

            if (lives == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep (500);
                SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name);
            }

            // перенесем ниже, чтобы не было -1 здоровья
            Lives--;
            rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rigidbody.AddForce (transform.up * 12.0F, ForceMode2D.Impulse);


            Debug.Log (lives);
        }
    }

    private void CheckGround()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll (transform.position, 0.3F);

            isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;

        if (!isGrounded) State = CharState.Jump;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        Bullet bullet = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Bullet> ();
        if (bullet && bullet.Parent != gameObject) 
        {
            ReceiveDamage ();
        }
    }
}

public enum CharState
{
    Idle,
    Run,
    Jump
}
```

Comment: Если урон идет как входной параметр, то, ставить таймер, или таймстамп времени последнего полученного урона, и при условии если время еще не закончилось, просто выходить из метода получения урона. Возвращая ничего или 0 как полученный урон.

Comment: @Birdy Не могли бы вы привести пример кода? Я мало чего еще понимаю в юнити, пару дней назад только занялся этим, так сложно что-то понять=(

Comment: Посмотри на ютубе туторы для начала

Comment: @Xumera_hZ я смотрел, но такие моменты там не объяснялись

Comment: @Programmer192334 для начала, добавьте ваш код получения урона персонажем в вопрос, что бы я смог вам помочь.

Comment: @Birdy добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой метод, если что-то не получится, то попробуйте поиграть с игровым временем.

```
// предыдущее/текущее (в случае если равно нулю, или перезаписали) время после получения урона
private int _prevTimeStamp = 0;

public override void ReceiveDamage()
{
    // запишем тукущее количество тиков, со старта ОС, и будем
    // записывать каждый раз в переменную для срванения с предыдущим
    var timeStamp = Environment.TickCount;
    _prevTimeStamp = _prevTimeStamp == 0 ? timeStamp : _prevTimeStamp;

    if(TimeSpan.FromTicks(timeStamp - _prevTimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds < 2000 && _prevTimeStamp != timeStamp)// где 2000, миллисекунды, или же 2 секунды
    {
        return;
    }
    // если время вышло, то запишем текущее значение timemeStamp в _prevTimeStamp
    // в следующий раз будем сверять именно его.
    _prevTimeStamp = timeStamp;

    if (lives == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep (500);
        SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name);
    }

    // перенесем ниже, чтобы не было -1 здоровья
    Lives--;
    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rigidbody.AddForce (transform.up * 12.0F, ForceMode2D.Impulse);


    Debug.Log (lives);
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: 
An object reference is required to acess non-static member 'System.Time.Span.Ticks'

Comment: @ персонаж получает неуязвимость, но только она не исчезает=)

Comment: тоже самое получается:(

Comment: @Programmer192334 ... Я не понимаю, по логике все должно быть в идеале (почти), уберите проверку на 0, и допишите ниже установки текущего таймстампа такой код: `_prevTimeStamp = _prevTimeStamp == 0 ? timeStamp : _prevTimeStamp;`, так же подправил ответ

Comment: Ни в какую( вот скрин кода: https://imgur.com/a/ZrcN7 . Может что-то не правильно

Comment: @Programmer192334, ответ посмотрите, там не так написано.

Comment: Какой ответ? Я не много не понимаю

Comment: @Programmer192334, код в ответе был исправлен, его пробуйте

Comment: тоже самое, кажется этот способ не сработает

Comment: Судя по коду метода, он должен давать ожидаемый результат. @Programmer192334, можешь дать полный код? И пожалуйста, не используйте `Thread.Sleep (500);` в Unity3d :(

Comment: @MikhailEfremov сейчас кину, а почему лучше не использовать? на C# использовал просто, привык

Comment: @MikhailEfremov обновил код

Comment: @Programmer192334 Unity3d на одном потоке работает, останавливая его, ты останавливаешь весь движок. В этом случае лучше [корутины](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Coroutines.html) использовать.

Comment: @Programmer192334, в ответе описал метод, который работает.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так должно работать.

```
void ReceiveDamage()
{
  var timeStamp = Environment.TickCount;
  _prevTimeStamp = _prevTimeStamp == 0 ? timeStamp : _prevTimeStamp;

  if (TimeSpan.FromTicks(timeStamp - _prevTimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds < 2000)
  {
    return;
  }
  _prevTimeStamp = timeStamp;

  if (lives == 0)
  {
    Debug.Log("die");
    ReloadScene(); //метод перезагрузки сцены с задержкой
    return;
  }

  lives--;
  rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
  rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * 12.0F, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

  Debug.Log("hit");
}
```

Comment: Когда иду на препятствие, чтобы получить урон, при нанесении персонаж пропадает и идем спам такой ошибки: https://imgur.com/a/3KspR

Comment: а что вы в `ReloadScene();` поместили?

Comment: Thread.Sleep (500);
  SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name);

Comment: Нажмите на ошибку в Unity, там будет текст с ошибкой. Посмотрите на какой строке бросается, там и проблема.

Comment: если убрать RelodaScene(); и return; так же будет

Comment: В cameracontroller,  вот код: https://imgur.com/a/HDSFx

Comment: Измените метод Update() вот так: `if(target == null)
        return;
      Vector3 position = target.position;
      position.z = -10.0F;
      transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, position, speed*Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: Теперь просто пропадает персонаж

Comment: Сделал public override void, теперь просто проходит через препятствия и не получает урон, все доходит до if (lives == 0), а до lives-- не доходит код, через debug проверил

Comment: Нужно проверить переменную lives, где она и чем инициализируется

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aqylY